# How to compare two hard drives (or folder) to find missing files in one of them?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, comparison

I'm on macOS and, for context, I have one main hard drive that should include *all* my files (and yes, it's backed up with redundancy). And I have many other smaller hard drives that I have used over the years and have copied the contents to the main drive.

Now I want to discard the smaller HDDs, but want to make sure I don't lose anything.

The folder structure on the main drive might differ from the original folder structure in the smaller drives.

How can I compare two hard drives (or folders for that matter) and find files that are missing in one of them, disregarding their folder structure?

Comment: I use Beyond Compare (Scooter Software) for this. Windows, Mac, and Linux versions.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond Compare (Scooter Software) is very good software for this task (Drive and Folder compares) and is reasonably economical.

There are versions for Mac, Windows and Linux.

I use Beyond Compare to compare hard drives when I have copied A to B and made changes to one drive after the copy.

[Beyond Compare Features](https://www.scootersoftware.com/features.php)

> **COMPARE FILES, FOLDERS**
>
> You can compare entire drives and folders at high speed, checking just
> sizes and modified times.  Or, thoroughly verify every file with
> byte-by-byte comparisons.  FTP sites, cloud storage, and zip files are
> integrated seamlessly, and powerful filters allow you to limit what
> you see to only what you're interested in.
>
> Once you've found specific files you're interested in, Beyond Compare
> can intelligently pick the best way to compare and display them.  Text
> files can be viewed and edited with syntax highlighting and comparison
> rules tweaked specifically for documents, source code, and HTML.  The
> text contents of Microsoft Word .doc and Adobe .pdf files can also be
> compared but not edited.  Data files, executables, binary data, and
> images all have dedicated viewers as well, so you always have a clear
> view of the changes.
>
> **Compare files**
>
> Side-by-side display
>
> Color highlighting of differences within lines
>
> Display filters to show only differences
>
> Jump to next/previous difference within file or folder
>
> Printed and HTML comparison reports
>
> Unicode and MBCS support
>
> Thumbnail overview of comparison
>
> Can convert files before comparing them
>
> Compare files or clipboard contents
>
> Automatic backups when saving

Comment: Beyond Compare seems to be really powerful. Not sure I want to spend 30$ for a one-off task, but I might not have any other alternative.

I was looking into diff, but couldn't find a way to make it ignore folder structure.

Comment: You can try Beyond Compare as a trial version.  Still it is very inexpensive so excellent value.

Answer (score 0):

I use FreeFileSync https://freefilesync.org/, it has many options including updating a slave from a master or mirroring both sides, checking based on hash or timestamp, etc. I don't think it will compare files regardless of directory structure but that doesn't seem to make sense to me as there are many identically named files that can have different content/purpose depending on where it is in the directory structure.

If you want to minimize disk usage in archives might be worth using something like dupeGuru https://dupeguru.voltaicideas.net/ to remove identical files. Maybe you could consolidate everything into a drive then use this to weed out duplicates in different locations.